# Search result returning application server name instead of AAM name

Tags: 2010, enterprise-search, alternate-access-mapping

My Intranet portal built in Enterprise 2010 is returning application server name instead of the Alternate Access Mapping name of server, which should be 'sdintranet'. I have marked in the below image my concern. The search is returning correct results but the source URL has the application server name 'qdhqspap1'. I need to replace this name with 'sdintranet'.

Have I missed any configurations in Central Admin? Please advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'http://sdintranet' is now appearing in Search Results after creating a Server Name Mappings where I mentioned 'http://qdhqspap1/' as Address in index and 'http://sdintranet' as Address in Search Results.

Then in the Scope I changed the Folder Name to 'http://sdintranet' and selected ContentSource as 'Local SharePoint Sites'. After few span of time I performed a full crawl and my 'http://sdintranet' started appearing in all search results.

Server Name Mappings and Scope both links are available in Search Administration Page in Central Admin Site.